# React native firebase passwordless email fails to correctly redirect to app

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

Steps to error:

1. user enters email address and receive the correct email. The "dynamic link" also appears correct.
2. user presses the link, the email flickers and attempts to redirect but fails to do so
3. if a user manually opens the app, they are then logged in.

This behavior **ONLY** effects Android and **ONLY** the prod app distributed via store.
Local build redirects without any error.
Test build (using same credentials as prod) downloaded from the test store works without error.

The **Upload Key Cert** in the **Play Console** is the same as my local *release.keystore*

Both Upload and App signing key certs are included in the Firebase project

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I'm using AppCenter to build and distribute the app to the store. Also, frequently using CodePush to push patches.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="false" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="myappscheme"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.facebook.react'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + '/dotenv.gradle'


react {
    ~~~
}

/**
 * Set this to true to Run Proguard on Release builds to minify the Java bytecode.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore (JSC)
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US. Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

def app_env = project.env.get('APP_ENV')

copy {
    println "Switches google-services.json from $app_env"
    from "envs/$app_env"
    include 'google-services.json'
    into '.'
}

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace 'com.package.name'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.package.name'
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 4
        versionName '1.3.4'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            resValue 'string', 'CodePushDeploymentKey', 'abcdefg'
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue 'string', 'CodePushDeploymentKey', 'abcdefg'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation('com.facebook.react:react-android')

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation('com.facebook.react:hermes-android')
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply from: file('../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle'); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontNames: [ 'MaterialIcons.ttf' ] // Name of the font files you want to copy
]

apply from: '../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle'
apply from: '../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle'
```

I'm not sure how to debug since this only appears in the production version of the app in the Play store. Even the "Test" store version works.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RFIq.png

Comment: Not sure, try installing the prod build on a device and check the logs in Logcat. You may something useful

Comment: Do you use `myappscheme://` urls in the mail? I see only `<data android:scheme="myappscheme"/>` No https? Did you uploaded `.well-known/assetlinks.json` to your domain like https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks suggests